# Created cPanel subdomain, files inside the subfolder showing 500 error

Tags: .htaccess

I have setup a subdomain in cpanel like market.domain.com. The document root for this is /public_html/market/. I have places PHP files here

/public_html/market/info.php - this is working
/public_html/market/api/info.php - not working

any help for this will be much appreciated.

TIA

500 internal server error

Comment: Check your server error.log file .

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 3 things:

1. Check if there is any .htaccess file in the api or market directory. If yes, please rename the .htaccess file to .htaccess.original and see if the sub domain URL is working. If its working, then review the code in the .htaccess file.
2. Check the directory permission / ownership to see if its correct.
3. Check the error logs to find out exactly whats causing the problem.